# Are all fields defined on finite sample spaces also sigma-fields?

Tags: probability-theory

If we had a finite sample space $\Omega$, are any of the fields $\mathcal{F}$ that we could define for $\Omega$ also $\sigma-$fields? And if this is true, does that then mean that we can only encounter fields that are different from $\sigma-$fields when $\Omega$ is infinite (countable or uncountable)?

Comment: Yes. There is no difference between being closed under finite and discrete unions in this case.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is finite then $\sigma$-"whatever" is the same as "whatever" (fields, algebras, et cetera). Yes, $\sigma$ only comes in relevantly if $\Omega$ is infinite.

Comment: The only thing that differentiates a $\sigma$-field from a field is the stronger condition of closure under countable unions and not just under finite unions. In the case where the sample space $\Omega$ is finite, the two notions coincide since any (countable union of) subsets of $\Omega$ can be represented as a finite union of singleton sets of its elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several people already commented that the answer is yes, so I'll just post it as an answer.

Note, for instance, that a finite set $\Omega$ has only finitely many subsets, so any countable collection of subsets of $\Omega$ is in fact finite.  Thus any "countable union" of subsets can in fact be written as a finite union, since there are only finitely many distinct subsets appearing in the union.

This does indeed mean that the distinction between fields and $\sigma$-fields is only interesting when $\Omega$ is infinite.